How to set Default apps in Windows Settings by cmdline
How do you set the Default apps in system Setting by cmdline/script:

I'm not asking how to set a file-extension-association, that will not AFAIK change the "Default apps" in system Settings (although you can claim the end result will be the same, but again, that's not what I ask for)

My recommendation is set the default application through the GUI then export the key that’s created.

To find out what keys are changed, take a snapshot of Registry before, set default app, and diff with another snapshot afterwards. Tools such as RegistryChangesView, https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/registry_changes_view.html, can help.
